# Elasticsearch - importing data from another data folder

Tags: elasticsearch

I copied a data folder from another ES instance into a new ES install (same version). After starting my new Elasticsearch, it does not recognize the new data.

I tried renaming the cluster.name in the YML config file, but no success.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you had a look at the logs by chance?

Comment: Good question... Where do I find the logs?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html